# Integer overflow not overflowing?

Tags: c

I'm doing the ctf challenge from [247CTF](https://247ctf.com) "impossible numbers".
The  challenge is about integer overflow, and consists of the following file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int impossible_number;
    FILE *flag;
    char c;
    if (scanf("%d", &impossible_number)) {
        if (impossible_number > 0 && impossible_number > (impossible_number + 1)) {
            flag = fopen("flag.txt","r");
            while((c = getc(flag)) != EOF) {
                printf("%c",c);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can try the challenge at:

```
$ nc 1765a1cbe1629dfc.247ctf.com 50458
```

It's pretty simple, you need to trigger this case:

```
if (impossible_number > 0 && impossible_number > (impossible_number + 1))
```

Which you do by inputting 2147483647, which then overflows in the line `impossible_number + 1`.
This works for me, but I have also tried running it locally in vs code, and here the if statement is not triggered.
After doing some debugging, I have concluded that this is the proporsition that fails:

```
impossible_number > (impossible_number + 1)
```

This is really weird to me, I have even tried adding some prints of the values:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int impossible_number;
    FILE *flag;
    char c;
    if (scanf("%d", &impossible_number)) {
        printf("impossible nr: %d \n", impossible_number);
        printf("plus one nr: %d \n",impossible_number + 1 );
        if (impossible_number > 0 && impossible_number > (impossible_number + 1)) {
            flag = fopen("flag.txt","r");
            while((c = getc(flag)) != EOF) {
                printf("%c",c);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which prints this:

```
impossible nr: 2147483647 
plus one nr: -2147483648
```

This makes no sense to me, why does this work on the 247CTF server, but not when I run it?

Comment: `if (scanf("%d", &impossible_number))` will not work correctly if there's an error or if there's an `EOF` (when `scanf` return `EOF`). Remember that only *zero* is considered false, and that `EOF` is not zero.

Comment: Since signed overflow is undefined, the compilers are allowed to optimize away the condition entirely. Do you have optimizations enabled?

Comment: Integer overflow is undefined behavior - drawing conclusions about how or why it "works" (or doesn't) is literally a meaningless exercise.  Code that depends on any type of undefined behavior in any way can never be said to "work" - the best ***anyone*** can say about C code that invokes undefined behavior is "I haven't observed it fail - ***yet***."  And even then, the concept of "fail" is also meaningless.

Comment: The behavour of signed integers on overflow is undefined, so you should not expect a predictable outcome when comparing a result.

Comment: The page you linked doesn't seem to show anything relating to the question, but if the problem is to determine if the arithmetic *would* overflow, you can check for that without actually making it overflow.

Comment: The condition `if ((number > INT_MIN) && (number - 1) > number)` is "equivalent" and does not suffer from UB :)

Comment: The 247CTF game is about hacking, so you should probably expect that it will exploit some undefined behavior that you may not be able to replicate on your own. Real hackers don't always have access to the exact hardware and configuration they're trying to gain access to, either.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: Re “drawing conclusions about how or why it "works" (or doesn't) is literally a meaningless exercise”: Rubbish. Software engineers can use knowledge about how compilers and other things operate with or on undefined behavior to help diagnose bugs. Malicious parties can use the knowledge to find vulnerabilities and exploit them. Security researchers can use it to counter vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been noted in the comments, signed integer overflow is undefined behavior in C.

The game's version of the program was apparently built with a compiler that handles it naively: by actually adding 1 to `impossible_number` (using ordinary two's-complement addition), then comparing the result with `impossible_number` and executing the `fopen` if it's less.  In that case inputting 2147483647 works, as you saw.  In my tests, clang without optimizations behaves like this.

But there are other possibilities.  For instance, recent versions of GCC, even with `-O0`, notice that the test can't be true in any case when overflow doesn't occur.  And if overflow does occur, the behavior is undefined, and so the compiler is at perfect liberty to do whatever it likes in that case.  So it is allowed to assume that the test can't ever be true, and that's what it does: it optimizes away the entire `if` block, including the test itself which is now redundant.  [Try on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/joo8Ynfba); note that the generated assembly contains no call to `fopen` at all.  So this program compiled with GCC is not vulnerable.  The same is true for clang if optimizations are enabled (`-O1` or higher).

(You can force the "naive" behavior in either compiler by compiling with `-fwrapv`.  There is also `-ftrapv` which forces the program to abort if signed integer overflow ever occurs; it has a substantial runtime performance cost, but  might be desirable when security is critical.)

Thus for an attack like this, you have to not only read the source code of the vulnerable program, but also be able to discover or guess what is in the compiled code that the victim is actually using.